# Cannot Find the TensorFlow Developer Certificate Plugin in the PyCharm Plugin Marketplace

Tags: tensorflow, pycharm

I paid to take the **TensorFlow Developer Certificate** exam, and I'm now supposed to install the TensorFlow Developer Certificate plugin into PyCharm. I go to PyCharm Plugins and search for "TensorFlow", but there's no TensorFlow Developer Certificate plugin available.

[PyCharm Plugin Search Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4Psx.png)

I have installed four different versions of PyCharm because I thought it was a version problem, but the TensorFlow Developer Certificate plugin cannot be found in any of the four versions:

pycharm-community-2021.1.1.exe
pycharm-community-2020.3.5.exe
pycharm-community-2020.1.5.exe
pycharm-community-2019.3.5.exe

Am I supposed to do something else to be able to see this plugin in the search?  Thanks so much in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 4):

I solved the problem by manually downloading the TensorFlow Developer Certificate exam plugin at:

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13812-tensorflow-developer-certificate

I then extracted it to this directory:

C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.1.1\plugins

It's strange that it had to be manually installed though. The exam manual states that all you have to do is look for the plugin at the PyCharm Plugin Marketplace.

Comment: I contacted the TensorFlow Certificate Team, and they told me it's not showing up because they were in the process of updating the plugin. They got done with the update this morning (May 10), and now the TensorFlow Certificate plugin shows up when you search for it in the PyCharm Plugin Marketplace.